# SQL WHERE IN with limited and sorted results per IN id

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

I didn't quite know how to describe this, so please excuse the title...

I'm trying to write a function to retrieve the most recent message belonging to a conversation, when provided with an array of conversation IDs.

My "message" table looks as follows:

```
id | conversationId | body           | createdDate
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1              | Hello          | 2020-06-09 01:01
2  | 1              | How are you?   | 2020-06-09 01:02
3  | 2              | Hi             | 2020-06-09 01:02
4  | 1              | I'm good, you? | 2020-06-09 01:03
5  | 2              | Hey there!     | 2020-06-09 01:04
```

I got as far as to query:

`SELECT * FROM "message" WHERE "conversationId" IN (1, 2) ORDER BY "createdDate" DESC`

As expected this returns all of the messages, which match the conversation id's provided, sorted by most recent `createdDate`.

I'm a little confused at how I can `LIMIT` to only include the first result (most recent `createdDate`) for each `conversationId`.

The output I'm looking for would be:

```
id | conversationId | body           | createdDate
-------------------------------------------------------
4  | 1              | I'm good, you? | 2020-06-09 01:03
5  | 2              | Hey there!     | 2020-06-09 01:04
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a typical greatest-n-per-group problem. In Postgres, a simple and efficient way to address this is `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (conversationId) m.*
from messages m
-- where conversationId in (...)    -- if needed
order by conversationId, createdDate desc
```

Comment: Very interesting. From PostgreSQL manual: "Note that the first row of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first". One learn something new every day. +1

Comment: @TheImpaler: in Postgres, `distinct on` really is the way to go for this kind of problem, as it  is specifically designed (and optimized) for that purpose. I wish other databases had the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use window function `row_number`

```
select
  id,
  conversationId,
  body,
  createdDate
from
(
  SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by conversationId order by createdDate desc) as rn
  FROM "message" 
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: This answer is correct. I would name the expression `rn` instead of `rnk` since the latter gives the impression of "rank"; but yeah, this is just a cosmetic issue. +1

Answer (score 1):

as stated before in other answers DISTINCT ON would be easiest way. but it comes with restrictions. especially with sorting order.

without restrictions, this could be achieved with these 2 methods, also without using a GROUP BY

---

A) just a simple self ANTI JOIN;

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    "message" AS m
    LEFT JOIN "message" _m ON _m."conversationId" = m."conversationId" AND _m."createdDate" > m."createdDate"
WHERE
    _m."id" IS NULL
```

it is called ANTI JOIN, because normally we want the "joined" results and in this case we don't want them. so do a self left outer join with the required criteria which is the highest timestamp in the conversation.

to better understand this concept, you can run the query without the _m."id" IS NULL condition. this will give you all the matching records:

```
Right Side : "m"                       || Left Side : "_m"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | conversationId | createdDate      ||  id | conversationId | createdDate      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1              | 2020-06-09 01:01 ||  2  | 1              | 2020-06-09 01:02
1  | 1              | 2020-06-09 01:01 ||  4  | 1              | 2020-06-09 01:03
2  | 1              | 2020-06-09 01:02 ||  4  | 1              | 2020-06-09 01:03
3  | 2              | 2020-06-09 01:02 ||  5  | 2              | 2020-06-09 01:04
4  | 1              | 2020-06-09 01:03 || NULL
5  | 2              | 2020-06-09 01:04 || NULL
```

the records with 4 and 5 doesn't have any matches, because there are no higher dates in those conversations. when there is no matching record for the left side, we can be sure that right side has the highest timestamp for that conversation.

---

B) a simple SUBQUERY

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    "message" m
WHERE
    m."id" = (
        SELECT
            "id"
        FROM
            "message"
        WHERE
            "conversationId" = m."conversationId"
        ORDER BY
            "createdDate" DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

the SUBQUERY in the condition always returns the id of the record with the highest timestamp in the conversation. we use its return value to limit the records in the main query.